# The recompiled kernel is different from the official release

Tags: apt, kernel, compiling

1. My kernel version is:

```
Linux version 4.15.0-140-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-026) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)) #144~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 21:24:12 UTC 2021
```

2. Get the source code.

```
apt-get source linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)
```

3. Copy the configuration file.

```
/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.15.0# cp /boot/config-4.15.0-140-generic .config
```

4. Start compiling.

```
make -j8
```

5. I found that the recompiled System.map file was different from the official release.
   There are obviously more official calls to arch_local_irq_enable.
   Is there something wrong with my compilation steps? Or is there a problem with the source code?

```
/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.15.0# grep ffffffff81002010 System.map -C3
ffffffff810016c0 t xen_hypercall_arch_6
ffffffff810016e0 t xen_hypercall_arch_7
ffffffff81002000 T __startup_secondary_64
ffffffff81002010 t run_init_process
ffffffff81002040 t try_to_run_init_process
ffffffff81002080 t initcall_blacklisted
ffffffff81002150 T do_one_initcall
/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.15.0# grep arch_local_irq_enable System.map
ffffffff810930c0 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff819b636f t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff819b6bbc t arch_local_irq_enable

/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.15.0# grep ffffffff81002010 /boot/System.map-4.15.0-140-generic -C3
ffffffff810016c0 t xen_hypercall_arch_6
ffffffff810016e0 t xen_hypercall_arch_7
ffffffff81002000 T __startup_secondary_64
ffffffff81002010 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff81002020 t run_init_process
ffffffff81002050 t try_to_run_init_process
ffffffff81002090 t initcall_blacklisted
/usr/src/linux-hwe-4.15.0# grep arch_local_irq_enable /boot/System.map-4.15.0-140-generic
ffffffff81002010 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff81038c80 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff810931f0 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff810c1b20 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff810e7fd0 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff819b58cb t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff819b5a87 t arch_local_irq_enable
ffffffff819b62cf t arch_local_irq_enable
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Is the difference a problem ? You compiled the kernel from source for some reason, and you get a binary that i different - that doesn't surprise me.

Comment: compare the .config file as it is after the compile with the original that you copied. Often it gets re-written and often you will find the compiler version is different. But, and as @SorenA already mentioned, a different memory map is not a surprise.

Comment: Interesting, I have many kernel installed (number of kernels @ number of arch_local_irq_enable):  2@2; 5@3; 1@4; 6@5; 15@8; 1@14; 1@15; 4@17.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, but I don't think the question is relevant. @David

Comment: I want to compile vmlinux myself for crash analysis. `diff -y .config /boot/config-4.15.0-140-generic --suppress-common-lines`, there is no difference. Not only the address is different, but the calling function is different. I didn't find this problem on CentOS.@DougSmythies

Comment: Just a reminder 16.04 reaches end of standard support on April 22 2021. You may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. End of Stand Support means no more support or updates. You may not ask questions here either as 16.04 will be off topic. If you sign up for ESM you can still get security patches but that is all.